# C# - How to access instances of a particular type that are used in Func<int> delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, func

In Factory.Process(..) method, I want get hold of instances of MyClass that are being used in the lambda expression of the Func delegate. But, How? 
Can someone help me find a way to do it.

Edit: This is an artificial example that demonstates my need. My intention behind this approach is that, I want to keep track of (or subscribe to) all the MyClass objects that are used in the delegate definition. So that, I can recalculate my total value whenever any MyClass object value is changed. Please suggest as to how to go about to solve this.

Note: Expression tree doesnt seem to help in my case because I cant modify my parameter type at this moment and it restricts the usage of my complex function definitions.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value;

    public MyClass(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var obj1 = new MyClass(10);
        var obj2 = new MyClass(20);
        Factory.Process(() => obj1.Value + obj2.Value);
    }
}

public static class Factory
{
    public static void Process(Func<int> function)
    {
        var total = function.Invoke();

        // Here, apart from invoke, I want to access the all the instances of MyClass that are used in 'function'
        // but how do I get to obj1 and obj2 objects through the 'function' delegate?
    }
}
```

Comment: For all practical purposes, you can't.  You'd need to inspect the IL code of the method referred to by the delegate

Comment: Can you please clarify the real problem you are trying to solve.. the example looks artificial, obviously to make it easy to ask and answer the question... but something doesn't seem right here.. Any answer, without understanding real problem will probably be **hackish** or not **acceptable**.. Few which come to mind, pass the objects to Process method... OR slice and dice the Func to get the objects you need, likely to work in a way, very specific to the scenario.

Comment: As Servy says, since the object references are embedded in the anonymous method as values of captured variables, there's no general way to do this without actually inspecting the IL for the anonymous method and seeing what objects it uses. You would need to change the basic design to do this "the right way" (e.g. construct an Expression for the factory method and pass that instead of an actual compiled method). The fact that this would be so awkward to solve should be a strong hint that you're probably approaching the bigger problem the wrong way.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your edit is entirely invalid.  This question is about delegates, and using reflection is the only way that this information can be extracted from a delegate.   The question is *not* about expressions, as is very clear throughout the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you type an input parameter as just `Func<T>` it's not an expression, but just a lambda syntax for delegates.

If you want to be able to access *the expression* and do some *reflection* and/or analysis, you need to type your parameters as `Expression<T>`. For example: `Expression<Func<int>>`. This turns your expression into an *expression tree*.

[Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) enable you to access the expression like a data structure. Once you've finished analyzing your expression tree, you can call `yourExpression.Compile()`, and this will compile your expression tree into a delegate that can be invoked as any other delegate (either named and anonymous ones).

For example, `obj1` would be accessed this way:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj1 = new MyClass { Value = 1 };
    var obj2 = new MyClass { Value = 2 };

    Expression<Func<int>> expr = () => obj1.Value + obj2.Value;

    BinaryExpression binaryExpr = (BinaryExpression)expr.Body;
    MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)binaryExpr.Left;
    MemberExpression fieldExpr = (MemberExpression)memberExpr.Expression;
    ConstantExpression constantExpr = (ConstantExpression)fieldExpr.Expression;

    dynamic value = constantExpr.Value;
    MyClass some = value.obj1;
}
```

### Update

OP said in some comment:

> unfortunately, changing from parameter Func to
>   Expression> doesnt seem to work well in my situation because,
>   expression tree is restricting my function delegate definition from
>   using assignment operators and statement body.

My answer to this is you want an unexisting universal solution, because any other solution might compromise maintainability.

Maybe there's an alternative that will allow you to stay with delegates instead of expression trees: a delegate with an `out` parameter which would contain a collection of objects involved in there...

Since standard BCL `Func` delegates don't come with output parameters, you can declare your own `Func` delegate as follows:

```
public delegate TResult Func<out T>(out IDictionary<string, object> objects);
```

...and your delegate should set the so-called `out` parameter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }  
    }

    public delegate void Func<out T>(out IDictionary<string, object> objects);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<int> someFunc = (out IDictionary<string, object> objects) => 
        {
            var obj1 = new MyClass { Value = 1 };
            var obj2 = new MyClass { Value = 2 };

            int result = obj1.Value + obj2.Value;

            objects = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "obj1", obj1 }, { "obj2", obj2 } };

        };

        IDictionary<string, object> objectsInFunc;

        someFunc(out objectsInFunc);

    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask about expressions, he asked about delegates.

Comment: @Servy I'm exhausted about your downvotes and destructive comments.

Comment: Yeah, how dare I explain to you why your answer is wrong.  I really should have upvoted your incorrect answer and pretended that there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Servy In addition, READ THE WHOLE ANSWER, where I say "it's not possible using delegates", and then, I give an alternative. When I watched you in some comment on this question I wasn't sure about posting here, because I know how easy you've your pointer in the downvote button, and sometimes it seems like you're wasting your time with comments like your first one. "You're wrong, bang, downvote". Ok, SO gives you this freedom but I'm nearly to 100% sure that OP will find my answer useful.

Comment: You *didn't* say that it's not possible using delegates.  You just posted a quote *that you never actually said*.  In addition to that, *it's not actually true*.  It *is* possible using delegates, it's just a lot harder.  Finally, of course I'm going to downvote an answer that's wrong.  That you would expect anything else from anyone baffles me.  That you think it's a good idea to post wrong answers, and have them be upvoted, is just astonishing to me.

Comment: If a path is a dead end, it’s a good idea to take another one, even you have to change your original goals slightly.

Comment: @Servy The question isn't wrong. And you say, I didn't say "it's not possible with [...]". Just read this sentence in my answer: **If you want to be able to access the expression and do some reflection and/or analysis, you need to type your parameters as `Expression<T>`**. In addition, having to deal with IL it's not a "it's possible" answer. It's very very obvious OP is asking a solution using C#, not MSIL... Again, **the answer isn't wrong**, you're who's in the wrong way: the answer solves the issue, and now it's up to the OP to decide if my solution solves his/her issue.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Well, at least you figured out how to actually quote yourself this time.  Of course, that quoted section has the same problem in that you don't *need* to use an `Expression`, it just makes the solution easier.  You choose to not answer the actual question asked and instead answer a different, easier, question, and incorrectly implied that the harder problem is impossible.  If the OP wants to solve the problem that he has, using IL is probably the only way, whether he wants to use it or not.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer If it's *possible* for him to change his requirements, which it may very well not be, then we could at least *start* having a discussion about this answer, even though it has quite a lot of problems once you get to that point.

Comment: @Servy Whatever, I know why I posted this answer, and I've something called **emphathy**, which makes me turn into the OP for some time and think what I would implement in some real-world project if I would be in OP's situation. And I wouldn't go with the IL solution, thus, my answer is a possible solution even if his original goal was using delegates. In addition, there's a good chance for the OP ignoring expression trees!! And that's why OP was asking for how to solve the problem using delegates... A lack of C# knowledge, and we're here to fill the gap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your empathy with the OP caused you to ignore his question, assume that his problem is dramatically different than what he actually asked for, and then to provide a low quality solution to that imagined problem?  If you are curious if the OP is capable of using expressions, or concerned that he might not even be aware of them, then a comment to that effect would be entirely appropriate asking if that is an option in context.

Comment: @Servy If he can use or not expression is OP's concern, and SO is about options. This is my proposal, and there're other answers with other solutions. OP will decide the best approach for him/her. And, in fact, SO has many answers to one question, because maybe OP finds useless my answer because OP can't switch to expression trees, but future readers may find my answer useful, even if it's not the one that was useful for the OP. Publish your answer and stop this noise please..........

Comment: Because of course those other people coming to find the question are also going to have a lambda with a plus operator that closes over two instances of classes of the same type that is the type of interest that access a property that isn't of interest.  They aren't going to have any variations on any of those points...

Comment: @Servy You say that "It is possible using delegates, it's just a lot harder." Can we do it in C#? If so, can you please let me know as to how to do it or atleast provide a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks for your response. I already knew that it is possible to do it with the help of expression trees. But I dont have the luxury to change the definition of Factory.Process method to use expression tree. Since we are already discussing about solving in in expression trees, can you let me know as to how to better handle this when the delegate is more complex(like having more arithmatic operations on more objects or more multiple lines of code). The idea is that this logic should work for any code that is passed in to the function delegate. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @YaserIrfan I would go for expression trees, since they're a definitive solution to handle your case... And about more complex scenarios, you might need to use some kind of recursion with some `if` statements to handle as many use case as you might need in your project :\

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer unfortunately, changing from parameter Func<int> to Expression<Func<T>> doesnt seem to work well in my situation because, expression tree is restricting my function delegate definition from using assignment operators and statement body.

Comment: @YaserIrfan Then you should reconsider your case... I mean, you won't find a definitive solution to your issue, or, at least, a maintainable one... I'm going to update my answer with an alternate solution, let me know if it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

As written, it cannot be done, because you're trying to access information about the exact code and would thus need to examine the incoming IL (since the actual C# code is gone after compilation).

However, it WOULD be possible using the metacode libraries of `System.Linq.Expression` namespace, but only if you swap out `Func<int>` for `Expression<Func<int>>`. With this, you would then be able to walk the [expressions tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) created by your lambda call. Using an `Expression` in place of another delegate type also tells the compiler to make an expression tree, rather than actually compiling the code, so this won't work if you pass a direct method or try to examine non-expression tree objects the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you change the parameter type of `Process` to `Expression<Func<int>> expr`:

```
public static void Process(Expression<Func<int>> expr)
{
    Func<int> function = expr.Compile();
    var total = function();

    Expression left = ((BinaryExpression)expr.Body).Left;
    Expression leftObjExpr = ((MemberExpression)left).Expression;
    Expression<Func<MyClass>> leftLambda =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass>>(leftObjExpr);
    Func<MyClass> leftFunc = leftLambda.Compile();
    MyClass obj1 = leftFunc();
    int value = obj1.Value; // ==> 10

    // Same with right operand...
}
```

Note that you can still invoke the function; you just have to compile the lambda expression to get a callable function.

However, this will only work with a binary expression. If you want to parse all kinds of expressions, this becomes quite complicated. You best solve this problem with the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).